# Trouble scraping reviews using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the reviews from this website: https://www.sephora.com/product/the-porefessional-face-primer-P264900. Here is an example of the syntax I find when I inspect a review:

```
<div class="css-7rv8g1 " data-comp="Ellipsis Box ">So good! This primer smooths my skin and blurs my pores so well! But, it is pretty mattifying so if you want a dewy look, this might not be for you.</div>
```

I have tried the following code, which returns an empty list:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/…/chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.sephora.com/product/the-porefessional-face-primer-P264900'
driver.get(url)
reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ratings-reviews']//div[@data-comp='Ellipsis Box']")
```

I have tried calling other `find_elements` methods on `driver` without success. I have also tried the solution outlined at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131938/how-do-i-extract-data-from-dynamic-updating-webpages), but got a `TimeoutException` from running the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='tabpanel0']/div//b[contains(., 'What Else You Need to Know')]"))))
reviews = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-comp='GridCell Box']//div[@data-comp='Ellipsis Box']")))
```

How can I use Selenium to scrape reviews from this page on Sephora’s website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a space in your xpath.  You have 'Ellipsis Box' when it should be 'Ellipsis Box '

```
//div[@id='ratings-reviews']//div[@data-comp='Ellipsis Box ']
```

I was able to find 6 elements using the corrected xpath.